# Alternative to property files in IBM WebSphere environment (WAS)

Tags: properties, websphere

Im looking for an alternate way to store "environment variable" in the current environment that I'm currently working on. (IBM WebSphere)

We are currently in a situation where we have to many property files that it has become difficult to manage.

Im looking for a way to consolidate all these properties into a central place that is easily administered by the admin team.

Some of the options I have explored include :

- Storing properties in the database.
- Consolidation into a single text file

Any other suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what kind of properties, whether they are part of multiple applications or just one, whether you want them shared across applications, whether they are deployed in WAR files or elsewhere, etc.

Answer (score 2):

@Nic Willemse: you may want to use jndi namespace binding provided by websphere...go to admin console-> environment and specify new namespace binding key,value pair.

Comment: Will this persistent on a server restart ?

Comment: @Nic: definitely persistent in Websphere configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the kinds of properties you want to be edited by the admin team. Usually for us those are the items that should be managed as [JEE Resources](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/welc_resource.html) in web.xml, which allows them to be configured in standard locations in the WebSphere admin console.

Comment: Im looking more towards application type properties. Things that may change the behavior of the application.

Answer (score 0):

We keep most of our property files in c:\cfg\<>\

Makes it easy to have different configurations for different servers.